# Need help for simple code

Tags: variables, netlogo

I want to create a variable that neighbors with turtles on that neighbors patch are turtles with income X. Below code is what I have tried so far and of course it's still didn't work.
Please kindly help.

```
Let Neighbors1 Neighbors with [turtles-on with [income = "High"]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're gonna get much help for NetLogo here, mate...

Comment: Most NetLogo questions here on SO get answered pretty promptly, actually.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Most of my questions are answered promptly and correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `turtles-here` instead:

```
turtles-own [income]

to setup
  ca
  crt 200 [
    set income one-of ["Low" "High"]
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end

to test
  ask turtles [
    let _nbrs neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [income = "High"]]
    show _nbrs
  ]
end
```